# Move Exchange Server to new Domain in Same Forest

Tags: windows, active-directory, migration, exchange-server

We are migrating AD users to a new domain gradually, and we need to migrate our Exchange servers as well.  My thinking was to build a new Exchange server in the new domain and then move the user's mailboxes to the new Exchange server.  If there's a better way, or a known set of problems to be encountered, I'd love to get some help here.  We're talking around 500 users.  ADMT is being used to migrate the users over.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that with Exchange 2010 and higher, you can build new Exchange servers in your new domain and then just move the mailbox, if a trust exists.  Prior to 2010 apparently there is the inability to create the necessary trusts.  For those, export the users's mailbox into a .PST, then import after they are copied to the user's new domain-based laptop.